# How to create tables and schema direclty from an ER diagram in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

I am using MySQL Workbench for creating an ER diagram but the problem I am facing is to create tables directly from the ER diagram. I have created an schema, as you can see in the below diagram. Can't I just directly import the same schema from here and start inserting the values in `database`?

As you see in the figure below, the tables are already created as a part of ER diagram, but I don't understand why it is not showing in my database tab.

[image]

What's the procedure to directly import the same schema from here? I don't have an option to save it also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are after is called **forward engineering**. It means to take your model and create a real schema representation from it. Look in the Database menu. A detailed step-by-step instruction is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-forward-engineering-live-server.html.

This approach is more of an occasional type, because it doesn't give you a way to keep your model updated when the db content changes. A better approach is synchronization (also see menu), which is a two-way tool to update both model and server. Always be careful when you work on a production server. There can be destructive changes (like dropping a column).

Comment: Thank you so much it will definitely help me in future. Is the instructions same for Ubuntu machine as well?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same on all supported platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found one solution to such issue:

Basically you have copy each SQL Script from the tables, and run on the database side. Follow the following steps:

- Right click on tables in ER diagram side, and select `Copy SQL to clipboard`. Now you have the create command script on clipboard.
- Create the same schema and paste each `SQL Script from clipboard`.
- Run each SQL script one by one, and you are done!

This is not the best way to do such things, so if you know better methods do suggest!